# Not able to add document property button in CKEditor 4

Tags: ckeditor, pydio

I have upgraded my CKEditor in my ajaxplorer project.
I want to add document property in ckeditor 4 and I have tried in all ways. by adding code in class.AjxpCkEditor.js aven `ckeditor.js` but yet succeed. There was no folder for document property as "docprops" which was having in older version. Then I have  copied that folder and done some changes in class.AjxpCkEditor.js but its not working even I have done change in `ckeditor.js` but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin is not included in any of the 3 predefined presets, so you need to build your own version of CKEditor using the [online builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder).

Here's the plugin: http://ckeditor.com/addon/docprops and [plugins installation instructions](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins).